# Bootstrap glyphicons appearing as squares

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails, glyphicons

I'm running Rails 4 with the 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem (2.0.5) and some reason beyond me glyphicons appear solely as squares. The rest of bootstrap seems to be working fine. I've tried adding font-awesome directly but to no appeal. Any ideas on what cause bootstrap to function fully with the exception of glyphicons?

```
group :development do
 gem 'better_errors'
 gem 'binding_of_caller'
 gem 'meta_request'
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end
group :assets do 
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end
#for the sake of redundancy
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

Comment: Sounds like the path to your icon files is incorrect. You can easily check the location of the "squares" using dev tools to see what path it is calling then either move them to that location or change the path in the CSS or less file (I think it's in sprites.less).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to resolve this with

```
    *= require font-awesome
```

in my css file but am still confused as to why the twitter-bootstrap functioned with only the exception of the icons.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is a bit different than yours, but I'm still adding an answer in case anyone encounters this issue in future.

In my case all glyphicons used to work when I used bootstrap-sass version 3.0.3.0. After updating to bootstrap-sass 3.3.7, some glyphicons were displayed properly, others were displayed as squares.

There were 2 issues:

1. I had to add @import "bootstrap-sprockets"; line to application.css.scss file (it seems it's required after 3.3 version, and it wasn't required before)
2. I had to update rails-sass version to 5.0 from 4.0

FYI: I use 4.1.0 rails version

Confusingly for me, I didn't get an error about invalid sass version until I had explicitly set the version of bootstrap-sass to 3.3.7. Previously bundler chose this version automatically, and it didn't bother the bundler that the rails-sass version was incompatible. This sounds like something that couldn't happen, maybe I'm wrong about this last paragraph. I'm not a Ruby expert, I don't know if a bundler is capable of making such mistakes.